# ckeditor stops toolbar scrolling with the page

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I want to stop the toolbar from scrolling with the page up and down. I am using ckeditor 4 "beta" as i want to use it's inline editing feature.

I looked through the config class properties without any luck:

"http://nightly-v4.ckeditor.com/ckeditor_api/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config".

I took a look at the rest of the API for any hooks to the toolbar events with no luck either. I also tried to find where the toolbar listens to scroll events and remove it. No luck!

is there anyway to do this? Even if I need to dig into the code and change it by myself! I just need someone to point me to the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed there's no such an option right now. We'll add some, but first we have to release final v4 version :).

Anyway - to stop toolbar floating update `plugins/floatingspace/plugin.js:57` to:

```
function changeMode( newMode ) {
    var editorPos = editable.getDocumentPosition();
    updatePos( 'absolute', 'top', editorPos.y - spaceHeight - dockedOffsetY );

    mode = newMode;
}
```

It works for me - toolbar is displayed above the content and it doesn't move.